# How to get all global variable addresses and size at runtime through llvm or clang

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, global-variables, llvm

I'm analyzing c/c++ projects for memory errors tracking (out-of-bounds read/write). I would like to create at runtime a list of all global variables addresses , i.e. their boundaries.
Is there any workaround with LLVM (e.g. some llvm module pass) I can came up with, such that at runtime I'm able to locate all global variables and their corresponding size?

The desired outcomes is described in the following c pseudocode.

```
// Example of file.cc
int i;
int a[3] = {0, 1, 2};
char *s = "Simple string";

SOME_LIST_TYPE global_list;

void track_global_vars() {
  for (GLOBAL_VAR gv: GLOBAL_VAR gvs) {
    LIST_ITEM *li = (LIST_ITEM*) malloc(sizeof(LIST_ITEM));
    li->start = gv.getAddress();
    li->end   = li->start + gv.getSize();
    global_list.add(li);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  track_global_vars();
  // AT this point I would like to have:
  // global_list -> [i_start, i_end] -> [a_start, a_end] -> [s_start, s_end] -> ...

  // normal program execution
  return 0;
}
```

Any suggestion or workarounds?

Comment: There is no Reflection API in C++, so any solution you come up with is not going to be a standard language solution, and likely is going to be compiler-specific.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer to include the llvm framework, hoping to get some inspiration.

Comment: I think it would need to be a linker pass as that's when the memory sections are laid out.  Start by asking the linker for a map file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LLVM pass [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/lib/Transforms/Instrumentation/AddressSanitizer.cpp) already detects out of bounds memory accesses, including globals and also stack and heap. You can pass `-fsanitizer=address` to clang to use it. It's even been ported to GCC under the same flag. You can combine it with [UBSan](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html), the undefined behaviour sanitizer, as `-fsanitize=address,undefined` to catch even more errors, again available on both clang and gcc.

If for some reason you don't want ASan and you want to proceed with building a system that reflects on the sizes and addresses of global variables, you could declare a global in C `extern SOME_LIST_TYPE global_list;` and have an LLVM pass that fills in the data. Given a `llvm::Module *M` you can scan all global variables with `for (auto GV : M->globals()) {` ([doxygen](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html)) and you can build a constant "GEP" which steps over one element of the global's type to get the pointer to the end. See [the GEP faq](https://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html). As a tip with LLVM's API, note that most of these instructions, Add, Mul, GEP, exist in two forms, subclasses of `llvm::Instruction` and subclasses of `llvm::ConstantExpr`. You need the *second* form if you want to make it constant data you can initialize your array with.

Use `auto *the_array_to_fill = M->getNamedGlobal("global_list");` to get your global_list as an [llvm::GlobalVariable](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalVariable.html), then call `the_array_to_fill->setInitializer(...)` to set its data. You'll need to prepare the data in the type and layout that you want it in, maybe an array with a struct of two members (begin and end) or an array of all begins then all ends, whatever works for you. [The LLVM tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/index.html) covers how to create LLVM IR which you'll need to do to build up the types and (Constant!) values you initialize your global with.

You may also want to `the_array_to_fill->setLinkage(llvm::GlobalValue::AppendingLinkage);` so that you get all the globals from all translation units combined into one array when linking, instead of a "multiple definition" error or using weak linkage and only getting one of them discarding the rest.

Comment: Thank you! I knew about AddressSanitizer.cpp but I missed some points you clarified me.